# Run-Time error 424 Object required - just simply trying to open a file before convert to csv

Tags: vba, outlook

Complete newbie to VBA so please excuse this trivial question. I am simply trying to open the xls file before saving as csv.

The Workbooks.Open line gives me the runtime error. What am I doing wrong

```
Sub vba_code_to_convert_excel_to_csv()

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\EOD_Files\PROALPHA_08022017.xls")

wb.SaveAs FileName:="C:\EOD_Files\PROALPHA_08022017.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: you didn't declare wb! 
Dim wb as Workbook

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're in Outlook, and using another Office application's object model without qualifying it; the "Object Required" error you're getting is because VBA has no idea what `Workbooks` is referring to, so the `Workbooks.Open` member call (it knows it's a member call because, grammatically, it can only be that) can't be resolved at compile *or* run-time, so... boom.

Other than that:

- You're not declaring `wb`, so your code won't compile with `Option Explicit` turned on (and if it's not a habit already, make it one - VBA will happily compile code that contains typos without it). Actually the mere fact that you're getting that run-time error tells me `Option Explicit` is not specified, because if it were then your code would refuse to compile, because `Workbooks` is undefined.
- The procedure is *implicitly* `Public`.
- If the procedure is written in a class (or document, or form) module, then you have a public procedure with underscores in its name, which means no other class can ever `Implements` that class (it won't compile, *because* of the underscores) - this may or may not be an issue, but it's good to know nonetheless. Convention is to name procedures in `PascalCase`, like everything is in pretty much every VBA object model out there.
- You're *assuming* that `Workbooks.Open` is returning a valid object reference and that it doesn't raise any run-time error.
- You're hard-coding the file path, which makes the procedure a one-shot deal; after it ran once, it's completely useless.
- You're not closing the workbook you're opening.

Assuming a reference to the Excel object model, my implementation would look like this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SaveExcelWorkbookAsCSV(ByVal path As String)
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim app As Excel.Application
    Set app = GetExcelInstance

    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path)

    Dim newName As String
    newName = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) & ".csv"

    wb.SaveAs FileName:=newName, _
              FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
              CreateBackup:=False

CleanExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    wb.Close
    app.Quit
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub

Private Function GetExcelInstance() As Excel.Application
    'you can look that one up
End Function

Private Function GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ByVal path As String) As String
    'you can look that one up
End Function
```

Without a project reference to the Excel object model, you'll have to use *late binding* - that means you cannot use any of the types defined in the Excel type library, including constants and enum values; you need to define them yourself:

```
Public Sub SaveExcelWorkbookAsCSV(ByVal path As String)
    On Error GoTo CleanFail

    Dim app As Object
    Set app = GetExcelInstance

    Dim wb As Object
    Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path)

    Const xlCSV As Long = 6

    Dim newName As String
    newName = GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) & ".csv"

    wb.SaveAs FileName:=newName, _
              FileFormat:=xlCSV, _
              CreateBackup:=False

CleanExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    wb.Close
    app.Quit
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub

CleanFail:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume CleanExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You macro works for me, if you have Option Explicit you need declare the wb as workbook see below.

```
Sub vba_code_to_convert_excel_to_csv()
Dim wb as workbook

Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\EOD_Files\PROALPHA_08022017.xls")

wb.SaveAs FileName:="C:\EOD_Files\PROALPHA_08022017.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV,     CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```